# Move textfield up when keyboard appears leaves black bar behind

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

So I have it working when you click on a text field, it moves it up based on the size of the keyboard. That's great, but when I click away, the bottom of the original frame does not follow the keyboard moving down.

What I mean by this is that only when the keyboard is finished disappearing is when the view frame returns to its original y at 0. I have some photos below, in the second photo, you can see the keypad moving down, as the ugly black bar remains.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Here is what I do to make it animate:

```
@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification)
{
    guard let keyboardRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
        return
    }

    if notification.name == Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow || notification.name == Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame
    {
        view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardRect.height
    } else {
        view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
}
```

Inside viewDidLoad()

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp4uw.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O208.jpg

EDIT: I just want to clarify that the view frame does return back to its original state, it's just not animated nor does it do it in sync with the keyboard moving down. It does it after the keyboard moves down, and returns to y = 0 immediately without an animation. When I click the text field, it animates it beautifully as the keyboard moves up.

Comment: IQKeyboardManager is best for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Register keyboard Hide and Show Notification in you viewDidLoad()**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
 #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: 
 .UIKeyboardWillShow , object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide 
, object: nil)
```

**2. Called when keyboard hide and show**

```
@objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    adjustInsetForKeyBoards(show: true, notification: notification)
}

@objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
    adjustInsetForKeyBoards(show: false, notification: notification)
}
```

**3. Your logic to show and hide the keyboard with animation**

```
func adjustInsetForKeyBoards(show: Bool, notification: NSNotification){
  let userInfo = notification.userInfo ?? [:]

  let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
  let adjustment = (keyboardFrame.height * (show ? 1 : -1)) + 20
            self.yourView.contentInset.bottom += adjustment
}
```

Comment: Do you have any solution that doesn't involve a scrollview? Or is that the only way.

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate set window background color

```
window?.backgroundColor = .white
```